# Extract the pattern of Directory in GNU parallel

Tags: linux, gnu-parallel

I am running a command line software on multiple folder/samples.Each folder has such files *fastq.gz.

Below is an example of a folder.

Sample_EC_only/EC_only_S1_L005_I1_001.fastq.gz
Sample_EC_only/EC_only_S1_L005_R1_001.fastq.gz
Sample_EC_only/EC_only_S1_L005_R2_001.fastq.gz
Sample_EC_only/EC_only_S1_L006_I1_001.fastq.gz
Sample_EC_only/EC_only_S1_L006_R1_001.fastq.gz

I am trying to run this using gnu parallel for multiple softwares,but having issues with extracting the "ID" of the folder.

```
parallel -j $NSLOTS --xapply \
" echo {1}  \
/home/rob2056/software/cellranger-2.2.0/cellranger count --id  = "{basename} {1}"  \
                   --transcriptome=$ref_data \
                   --fastqs={1} \
 " ::: $TMPDIR/FASTQ/Sample*
```

I want to extract for e.g. "Sample_EC_only" as a pattern from the folder inside gnu parallel.  --fastqs is able to get the path using {1} ,but having issues with --id option.I have tried various options to extract a pattern from the paths in {1} but not working.

The --id parameter needs a pattern extracted from the path in {1} so that it can create a output dir.

Each {1} consists of e.g. (shown below only for one sample)

/tmp/FASTQ/Sample_EC_only

Comment: While GNU Parallel will work on multiline commands, it is recommended to define a bash function and call that instead. https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#No-command-means-arguments-are-commands In your case the " around {basename} {1} will be confusing to the average reader, as they are not matching. Instead the first is ending the " from the line before and the second is ended with the " before :::

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, all you are looking for is `{1/}` instead of `{1}`. It is the "basename" of the argument.  See [man parallel_tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Positional-replacement-strings) and the discussion of `--rpl` where we have that *replacement strings are implemented as*

```
     --rpl '{/} s:.*/::'
```

and *The positional replacement strings can also be modified using `/`* etc.
So `{1/}` is like removing all characters upto the final `/`.

---

You can create your own replacement shorthand strings using `--rpl` followed by a string which begins with a *tag* (`{/}` in the example above), then a perl expression, such as the substitute command above (`s:`*pattern*`:`*replacement*`:`).

I'm not sure what is allowed as tags, but we can use the tutorial example `{..}` for a positional tag, i.e. that can be used with `{`*number*`}`.  The perl expression to remove everything upto the last `/` followed by the word "Sample_" woudl be: `s:.*/Sample_::` so you need to add before `--xapply` the arguments

```
--rpl '{..} s:.*/Sample_::'
```

and then use `--id={1..}` to apply this replacement to arg 1.
If, for example, you want to remove the word upto the first underline `_`, rather than a fixed word `Sample`, you can use a pattern such as

```
--rpl '{..} s:.*/[^_]*_::'
```

---

The final command should look something like this:

```
parallel -j $NSLOTS --rpl '{..} s:.*/Sample_::' --xapply \
" echo {1}  \
/home/rob2056/software/cellranger-2.2.0/cellranger count --id={1/} \
                   --id2={1..} \
           --transcriptome=$ref_data \
           --fastqs={1} \
 " ::: $TMPDIR/FASTQ/Sample*
```

Comment: Also what would be the easiest way to extract "EC_only" from the pattern ?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: I want to add another parameter inside my command for e.g. id2  which takes "Ec_only" pattern from {1} (folder name in my case). I tried the method you suggested however not sure if it works    --id2= {/} s:.*/Sample_::

Comment: I added what I think you want as a final command at the end of my answer above. You need to add a `--rpl` which specifies the *tag* and the substitution command, then use the tag later on in the command.

Comment: The tag does not work --id2={1..} .The command wont run.(included the --rpl '{..} s:.*/Sample_::' in parallel)

Comment: I don't know what else to suggest. You should be getting `--id2=EC_only`. You don't say what you are getting. Update your Original Post with a new part showing exactly what you are now giving as command, and what you are getting as output, and what you expect to see.

Comment: Apologies,it works great.. I dint know that because of space between parameters and its values ,it would be giving errors, --id2 = {1..} was not working but --id2={1..} works.

Comment: You can chose any string as replacement string in `--rpl` but positional replacement strings will only work if the string starts with `{`.